# Lucene phase query case insensitive

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I am writing a query to do an exact match on a 'city' field.  The field/property is defined as:

```
@org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.NO)
private String city;
```

If I have the value of "New York", I want to find a match if user enters "new york", or some variation of case.   I am using the StandardAnalyzer for the entity, so I know that will lowercase all the tokens.  I don't tokenize since I want to match the phrase (Analyze.NO).

I tried to lowercase my search value, but no luck.

```
Query query = qb.phrase().onField(.....).sentence(location.toLowerCase()).createQuery();
```

If I don't lowercase the search term and the value is 'New York', results are returned. Searching for 'new york' does not return any result.

If I tokenize (Analyze.YES), then other cities like 'New Jersey' are returned.  I know I can use a wildcard query (searchTerm*), but I was hoping to be able to do a case insensitive search on a phrase.   Just not sure if that's possible unless you use the wildcard.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you would want to use an analyzer which emits the entire text as a single token while lower-casing the input.  In this case, you would want to use `analyze=Analyze.YES`, while specifying the appropriate analyzer (the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11782783/1260254) has code that looks like what you need) using `analyzer=@Analyzer(impl=your.fully.qualified.Analyzer.class)`.