# How to do case insensitive sorting using Hibernate Lucene Search?

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am able to get results using following code but the results are not sorted correctly. It display lowercase first and then uppercase characters.

Results getting:

```
upper
test
UPPER
Test
```

Expected Results;

```
 upper
 UPPER
 Test
 test
```

pattern can be any like uppercase (T) first and lowercase(T) after that.

Following is code for reference:

Prada - Entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Prada")
@XmlRootElement
@Indexed
@AnalyzerDef(name="customanalyzer", tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class), 
    filters = { 
        @TokenFilterDef(factory=ISOLatin1AccentFilterFactory.class),
        @TokenFilterDef(factory=LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)})
public class Prada implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@Fields({ @Field(index = Index.YES, store = Store.NO), @Field(name = "PradaName_for_sort", index = Index.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer")) })
@Column(name = "NAME", length = 100)
private String name;

public Prada () {
}

public Prada (Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Prada (Long id) {
    this.id = id;

}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}



public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.Prac.Prada[ id=" + id + " ]";
}

}
```

Found this analyzerDef solution somewhere but didn't worked for me. Could anyone provide me solution to that?

Main Code:

```
  FullTextEntityManager ftem = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(factory.createEntityManager());
  QueryBuilder qb = ftem.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity( Prada.class ).get();
  org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb.all().getQuery(); 
  FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = ftem.createFullTextQuery(query, Prada.class);
  fullTextQuery.setSort(new Sort(new SortField("PradaName_for_sort", SortField.STRING, true)));
  fullTextQuery.setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(150);
  int size = fullTextQuery.getResultSize();
  List<Prada> result = fullTextQuery.getResultList();
  for (Pradauser : result) {
    logger.info("Prada Name:" + user.getName());
  }
```

Following are versions of Lucene (which i cannot change):

```
 <hibernate.version>4.2.8.Final</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate.search.version>4.3.0.Final</hibernate.search.version>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
@AnalyzerDef(name = "customanalyzer",
tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = KeywordTokenizerFactory.class),
filters = {
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class),
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = PatternReplaceFilterFactory.class, params = {
        @Parameter(name = "pattern", value = "('-&\\.,\\(\\))"),
        @Parameter(name = "replacement", value = " "),
        @Parameter(name = "replace", value = "all")
    }),
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = PatternReplaceFilterFactory.class, params = {
        @Parameter(name = "pattern", value = "([^0-9\\p{L} ])"),
        @Parameter(name = "replacement", value = ""),
        @Parameter(name = "replace", value = "all")
    }),
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = TrimFilterFactory.class)
}
)
public class Prada implements Serializable {

@Fields({ @Field(index = Index.YES, store = Store.YES), @Field(name = "PradaName_for_sort", index = Index.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer")) })
@Column(name = "NAME", length = 100)
private String name;
```

Comment: Where is your `customanalyzer` code?

Comment: There is no code for that i have used inbuilt filters -> @AnalyzerDef

Comment: Have you tried to write your custom analyzer as mentioned [in this answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11792535/2815219)

Comment: It is sorting fine but it is not sorting special characters in Norwegian or other languages. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: You mean to say when [you use this analyzer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11792535/2815219), it given the results in the order that you want it to, viz., `upper,  UPPER, Test, test`, but it doesn't sort special characters? Right?

Comment: Yes. It is not sorting special characters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117771/discussion-between-raman-sahasi-and-fatherazrael).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use a tokenizer that does a tokenization for sorting. You need to use a KeywordTokenizer to be sure the tokens are kept as is.

Here is the analyzer we use for sorting at my former company:

```
    @AnalyzerDef(name = "TEXT_SORT",
        tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = KeywordTokenizerFactory.class),
        filters = {
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = PatternReplaceFilterFactory.class, params = {
                    @Parameter(name = "pattern", value = "('-&\\.,\\(\\))"),
                    @Parameter(name = "replacement", value = " "),
                    @Parameter(name = "replace", value = "all")
                }),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = PatternReplaceFilterFactory.class, params = {
                    @Parameter(name = "pattern", value = "([^0-9\\p{L} ])"),
                    @Parameter(name = "replacement", value = ""),
                    @Parameter(name = "replace", value = "all")
                }),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = TrimFilterFactory.class)
        }
    )
```

It's for the latest version of Hibernate Search so you need to adapt it. Obviously, you need a s/ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory/ISOLatin1AccentFilterFactory/ but I'm not sure if PatternReplaceFilterFactory already exists in 3.6.2.

Comment: Thanks. How to replace norwegian characters in above example-> Æ, Ø, and Å? Here Ø with O and Å with A. But replacing may not be good criteria as after replace we need to get exact results in List?

Comment: It's exactly what ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory (and ISOLatin1AccentFilterFactory in Lucene 3.6.2) does. See http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/3.6.0/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ISOLatin1AccentFilter.java#91 .

Comment: But it is not working as expected as Ø is coming between A & B and it should be between M & P

Comment: Can you share your updated code? (just the mapping part) Did you replace your StandardTokenizerFactory by KeywordTokenizerFactory as explained above?

Comment: Shared in description. I am using the same snippet given by you. It is displaying results correctly expect Norwegian Characters.

Comment: Did you reindex your data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117777/discussion-between-fatherazrael-and-guillaume-smet).

Comment: @Guilaume Smet

This case insensitivity issue is resolved. But i am still facing issue in formatting Norwegian characters. Another question created for same. Could you provide your suggestions?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39264308/how-to-do-case-insensitive-sorting-of-norwegian-characters-%C3%86-%C3%98-and-%C3%85-using-h