# How to do case insensitive sorting of Norwegian characters (Æ, Ø, and Å) using Hibernate Lucene Search?

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

æ, ø, å are latest letters in the norwegian alphabet

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z Æ Ø Å
```

When we try to sort it using Hibernate Lucene then  `Å clubs with A`, `Ø clubs with Ø`, `Æ clibs with A` which is wrong. For example:

Currrent Results:

> Aaalu, Åaalu, Baalu, Zaalu,

Expected Results:

> Aaalu, Baalu, Zaalu, Åaalu,

Following is working code:

```
@AnalyzerDef(name = "myOwnAnalyzer",
tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = KeywordTokenizerFactory.class),
filters = {
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class),
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = PatternReplaceFilterFactory.class, params = {
        @Parameter(name = "pattern", value = "('-&\\.,\\(\\))"),
        @Parameter(name = "replacement", value = " "),
        @Parameter(name = "replace", value = "all")
    }),
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = PatternReplaceFilterFactory.class, params = {
        @Parameter(name = "pattern", value = "([^0-9\\p{L} ])"),
        @Parameter(name = "replacement", value = ""),
        @Parameter(name = "replace", value = "all")
    }),
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = TrimFilterFactory.class)
}
)
public class KikaPaya implements Serializable {

@Fields({ @Field(index = Index.YES, store = Store.YES), @Field(name = "KikaPayaName_for_sort", index = Index.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "myOwnAnalyzer")) })
@Column(name = "NAME", length = 100)
private String name;
```

Main:

```
  FullTextEntityManager ftem = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(factory.createEntityManager());
  QueryBuilder qb = ftem.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity( KikaPaya.class ).get();
  org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb.all().getQuery(); 
  FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = ftem.createFullTextQuery(query, KikaPaya.class);
  fullTextQuery.setSort(new Sort(new SortField("KikaPayaName_for_sort", SortField.STRING, true)));
  fullTextQuery.setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(150);
  int size = fullTextQuery.getResultSize();
  List<KikaPaya> result = fullTextQuery.getResultList();
  for (KikaPayauser : result) {
    logger.info("KikaPaya Name:" + user.getName());
  }
```

Following are versions of Lucene (which i cannot change):

```
 <hibernate.version>4.2.8.Final</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate.search.version>4.3.0.Final</hibernate.search.version>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Could anyone suggests the way to get correct results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `org.apache.lucene.collation.CollationKeyFilter` class in Hibernate Search version 4.3.0.Final. Create your own collation filter factory:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.collation.CollationKeyFilter;
import org.apache.solr.analysis.BaseTokenFilterFactory;

import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.Locale;

public final class NorwegianCollationFactory extends BaseTokenFilterFactory {

    @Override
    public TokenStream create(TokenStream input) {
        Collator norwegianCollator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("no", "NO"));
        return new CollationKeyFilter(input, norwegianCollator);
    }

}
```

And the use this collation factory in your AnalyzerDef:

```
@AnalyzerDef(name = "myOwnAnalyzer",
tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = KeywordTokenizerFactory.class),
filters = {
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class),
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = PatternReplaceFilterFactory.class, params = {
        @Parameter(name = "pattern", value = "('-&\\.,\\(\\))"),
        @Parameter(name = "replacement", value = " "),
        @Parameter(name = "replace", value = "all")
    }),
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = PatternReplaceFilterFactory.class, params = {
        @Parameter(name = "pattern", value = "([^0-9\\p{L} ])"),
        @Parameter(name = "replacement", value = ""),
        @Parameter(name = "replace", value = "all")
    }),
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = TrimFilterFactory.class)
,
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = NorwegianCollationFactory .class)
}
)
public class KikaPaya implements Serializable {
```

More information about using this Collation filter with **hibernate search version 5** - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60738067/7179509

Answer (score 4):

I must admit it's not something common. As far as I can see, there is a Lucene module which uses ICU for locale dependent sorting.

See the lucene-icu artifact and especially the ICUCollationKeyFilter and ICUCollationKeyAnalyzer (the analyzer is a KeywordTokenizer with the filter). You will need to create the factory necessary to use it with Hibernate Search but it should be quite easy.

Can't really promise it will work but it's probably your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Got some idea from your response. I have passed Locale into SortField - new Locale("no","NO") and also removed ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory while indexing. I got all in Norwegian order. But when i do some changes in that field in Database. The position of that word got stick to that very place only; which disturbs sorting. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Ah OK, FYI, the locale support for SortField has been removed from recent Lucene versions so you can't rely on it anymore in recent versions. Did you reindex properly after having updated the database?

Comment: I have found some issues after above mentioned changes. I am unable to save and search data from database properly. It saved but search not work till next indexing and bug reopened :'( :'( . I have checked some NorwegianStemFilter classes exists.Trying using the same instead of locale.